# How do I limit a file/folder's name to a single line in Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, display, files, customization

I am using Ubuntu 18.10. All files/folders names are displayed in three rows as shown in the image below. Is there a way to display those names in a single row.

[image]

Like for the first song it is displayed as

```
08. Major 
Lazer – 
Lean On...
```

and I want it to look like,

```
08. Major...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via [`gsettings`](https://askubuntu.com/q/249887/158442):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view text-ellipsis-limit "['1']"
```

The key's description:

> A string specifying how parts of overlong file names should be
>   replaced by ellipses, depending on the zoom level. Each of the list
>   entries is of the form "Zoom Level:Integer". For each specified zoom
>   level, if the given integer is larger than 0, the file name will not
>   exceed the given number of lines. If the integer is 0 or smaller, no
>   limit is imposed on the specified zoom level. A default entry of the
>   form "Integer" without any specified zoom level is also allowed. It
>   defines the maximum number of lines for all other zoom levels.
>   Examples: 0 - always display overlong file names; 3 - shorten file
>   names if they exceed three lines; smallest:5,smaller:4,0 - shorten
>   file names if they exceed five lines for zoom level "smallest".
>   Shorten file names if they exceed four lines for zoom level "smaller".
>   Do not shorten file names for other zoom levels. Available zoom
>   levels: smallest (33%), smaller (50%), small (66%), standard (100%),
>   large (150%), larger (200%), largest (400%)

If you want to do this for the desktop as well, from [Can we (easily) turn off the line wrapping of icons on the desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1076581/158442):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop text-ellipsis-limit 1
```