# Change number of characters per line in a folder's name

Tags: directory, filename

I have noticed that the number of characters allowed per line in a folder's name is lower in Ubuntu 18.04 than it was in Ubuntu 16.04. This causes some long words to be forcefully split between two lines, resulting in an ugly appearance of my desktop. Is there any way to make Ubuntu accept longer lines on folders' names, that is, to change the number of characters that it allows in every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dconf-editor` to change the `text-ellipsis-limit` value in `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view`.

You may check this answer  to ["Can we (easily) turn off the line wrapping of icons on the desktop?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076634/1015711)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've found your post because I also have this question.
It's much more clear [how to add maximum number of filename's lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076581/can-we-easily-turn-off-the-line-wrapping-of-icons-on-the-desktop) in Nautilus icon view; not the exact answer, but maybe helps:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view text-ellipsis-limit 5
```