# Is there a way to change Icon label width

Tags: icons

Is there a way to change the width of a desktop icon label?  I'm using Ubuntu 18.0.4 11/17/2018.  A lot of the older responses reference options that aren't available in this version.   Example: "System-->Preferences-->Appearance-->Fonts" from 2010.  Those options are gone.

Comment: See if anything in https://askubuntu.com/a/1076634/248158 helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that changes only the maximum number of lines in the icon label, not the width of the label.