# How can I turn off word wrapping on nautilus (icon-view)?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, customization

Is there any way I can avoid the word wrapping on nautilus' icon-view? The following behavior annoys me:

[image: Nautilus icon-view, weird word wrapping.]

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076581/can-we-easily-turn-off-the-line-wrapping-of-icons-on-the-desktop) using `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop text-ellipsis-limit 1`, but it's not what I want. I'm just expecting nautilus to break my file and folder names in a better way (in this case, the lonely **n** letters should remain with "Compariso**n**" and "Deformatio**n**").